# Fastest way to get up to 3 numbers from 3 lists which add to another number?

Tags: language-agnostic, complexity-theory, time-complexity

Given 3 **sorted** lists `L1,L2,L3` all of size `n` and a number `x`, whats the fastest algorithm that can return up to 3 numbers, at most 1 from each list, such that the sum of those returned numbers add to `x`.

The fastest algorithm I can think of, checks all possible combinations which is `O(n^3)`. Is there a better way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get to O(n^2):

Consider only two lists, L1 and L2.  Set an index in L1 at the maximum element, and an index in L2 at an added zero element.  Now iterate both indexes together:  If the sum of the selected two elements is too big, step the L1 index down.  If the sum of the selected two elements is too small, step the L2 index up.  This takes O(2n) time.

Essentially, you're constructing a rectangle, with the elements of L1 being one axis and the elements of L2 being the Y axis.  Then you walk the boundary between the region of points representing sums that are too large and the region of points representing sums that are too small.

Executing the above algorithm once for each value in L3 gives an O(n^2) algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can at least get to `O(n^2 log n)` because, given 2 indices (`i` and `j`, say), you can do a binary search in `L3` for `x-L1[i]-L2[j]`.

If you don't need a value from every list, you could try each possible non-empty subset of lists individually; since there 6 such subsets, and solving for each will be faster than `O(n^2 log n)` (`O(n log n)` for pairs of lists, `O(log n)` for individual lists), the overall complexity is unchanged.